# Choppy Bluetooth Audio

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth speaker, the Creative SoundBlaster Roar SR20A. It works perfectly with my laptop (Intel AC Wireless 3165, I don't know the bluetooth module), except that after a while (especially while watching videos in a browser, such as YouTube), the audio begins to become super choppy, and with it, the video. It begins to act like the video is being repeatedly paused and unpaused, and this **always** happens after using the speaker for about 30 minutes. I don't know whether I need to download new drivers or something, any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I think it's caused by the driver cutting the connection as soon as there are no sounds to play - then, when there's a signal again, it somehow can't reconnect fast enough, resulting in the stuttering. A dirty fix is to constantly play a very quiet sound in the background so the connection keeps active. However, I'm still looking for a better solution.